# Trying to remove a file getting iterated by the same program

Tags: c++, vector, filesystems

As the title states, I'm scanning through the files in a directory after every few seconds using a loop.
Something like this...

```
        if (now >= nextTime)
        {
            for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(folderName))
            {
                filename.push_back(entry.path().filename().u8string());
                totalFilesNum++;
            }
         }
...
```

It basically loops the same code every few seconds `nextTime` and makes it super interactive. It keeps outputting the file data (name, size, etc.) every few seconds. Say, I drop a manually drop a new file in the directory, it takes that into consideration too.

So far so good. Now the problem is, when I try to delete one of the files in the directory. It doesn't let me do that and throws an `unhandled exception` instead. Following is my code for removing the file.

```
void RemoveFile()
{
    std::string folderName = "files";

    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(folderName))
    {
        if (entry.path().filename() == "25-Sep-19 9 03 18 PM.jpeg")
        {
            std::filesystem::remove(entry.path().c_str());
        }
        else {}
    }
```

For the record, using the same code I've tried deleting/removing a file in a different directory and it's working fine. Simply changed the directory `std::string folderName = "files_B"`with the same file name and it got deleted. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Queue up the delete requests and handle them between iterations of the directory.

Comment: What exception are you getting?